# How to append value from textarea to another view using backbone.js?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am beginner to backbone.js.

Actually i am developing chat application.

I given textarea to user to type a message and and i want when user clicks on send then that message should get appended to upper div which i specified.

how this can get achieved using backbone.js?
please see below code for textarea and submit button:

```
<textarea name="message" cols="20" rows="4" id="usermessage" ></textarea>  
<input name="submitmessage" type="submit" id="submitmessage" value="Send" />
```

please see below code for chathistory view :

```
<div id="chatHistory"></div>
```

I want to achieve this only using backbone.js. please help....

```
window.ChatHistoryView = Backbone.View.extend({
initialize: function(){
        this.render();
    },
render: function(){
// Compile the template using underscore
        var template = _.template( $("#chat_History").html(), {} );
        // Load the compiled HTML into the Backbone "el"
        this.$el.html( template );
    },
events: {
     //   "click input[type=button]": "doSearch"  
    },

});
   window.ChatInputView = Backbone.View.extend({
   initialize: function(){
    this.render();
},
render: function(){
    // Compile the template using underscore
    var template = _.template( $("#chat_Input").html(), {} );
    // Load the compiled HTML into the Backbone "el"
    this.$el.html( template );
},
events: {
    "click input[type=submit]": "updateChatHistory"  
},

updateChatHistory: function( event ){
    this.chatHistoryView.$e1.append();
    app.navigate('', true);
    window.history.back();
}
```

Please check and help me to solve this...

Comment: whats your backbone code or are you asking us to do it for you ?

Comment: Only backbone, what does that mean? I think you want to use jquery to do this, not backbone. jquery and backbone are often used together when creating backbone apps.

Comment: @adityasaxena Please see below code  :

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this. The easiest would be to expose a method in your history view that accepts a method and updates the view.

Update your ChatHistoryView like so

```
messages : [], //this is a collection of messages the history view is showing

//update your render method
render: function(){
   var template = _.template( messageTpl, { messages : this.messages } ); //note that message tpl is your raw template
   // Load the compiled HTML into the Backbone "el"
   this.$el.html( template );
}

addMessage : addMessage(message) { //message is an object
    messages.push(message);
    this.render();
}
```

And update your ChatInputView like so

```
updateChatHistory: function( event ){
    //construct an object
    var message = {
        text : this.$el.find('#usermessage').val()
    };
    this.chatHistoryView.addMessage(message); //pass the message to the history view

    // whatever other code you want that will do things
    app.navigate('', true);
    window.history.back();
}
```

This is just a crude example of the direction you should be taking. There a numerous improvements you can make to this depending on the structure of your project. An example would be to not redraw the whole page every time you insert one message. Might be worth it just to append the message to the end.